# How many implicit conversions can C++ do to convert one user-defined type to another when initializing class types?

Tags: c++, implicit-conversion

```
#include <iostream>

struct Gadget
{
  Gadget() { puts("Gadget default"); }
  Gadget(char const *a) { puts("Gadget-const char* constructor"); }
  Gadget(Gadget const &other) { puts("Gadget copy"); }
  ~Gadget() { puts("\nGadget destruction"); }
};

struct Work
{
  Work() { puts("default"); }
  Work(const Gadget &a) { puts("Work-Gadget constructor"); }
  // Work(char const *a) { puts("Work-const char* constructor"); }
  Work(Work const &other) { puts("copy"); }
  ~Work() { puts("\nWork destruction"); }
};

int main()
{
  using namespace std;
  Work w = "std";  // error here;
}
```

But

```
Work w("std"); // works fine
Work w = Gadget("std"); // works fine
Work w = Work("std"); // works fine
```

Is there any limit for implicit conversion that c++ can do?
If so then at what context does implicit conversion happen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Only one [user-defined conversion](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/cast_operator#Explanation) is allowed in [implicit conversion sequence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/implicit_conversion). (BTW standard conversions don't have such limits.) `Work w = "std";` performs [copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization), it requires two user-defined conversions, one from `char const *` to `Gadget`, and one from `Gadget` to `Work`.

`Work w("std");` performs [direct initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization), only one user-defined conversion (from `char const *` to `Gadget`) is required, then the converted `Gadget` is passed to the constructor of `Work` directly to construct `w`.

> the implicit conversion in copy-initialization must produce `T` directly from the initializer, while, e.g. direct-initialization expects an implicit conversion from the initializer to an argument of `T`'s constructor.

In `Work w = Work("std");`, a temporary `Work` is constructed explicitly as `Work("std")` (which works as above explained), then `w` is copy-initialized from the temporary `Work`.

In `Work w = Gadget("std");`, a temporary `Gadget` is constructed explicitly as `Gadget("std")`, then `w` is copy-initialized from the temporary `Gadget`; in which only one user-defined conversion (from `Gadget` to `Work`) is required.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I want to make one thing clear in initialization, if something comes before = is direct and comes after is copy. right?

Comment: @Vegeta You might check the linked pages I posted, which list all the syntax of direct initialization and copy initialization, then you can make out the difference easily.

Comment: Sure, Thanks for that

Comment: @Ted Lyngmo Sorry for the late